# How can I set Outlook up so that I can dial out using voip instead of a POTS?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, connection, microsoft-outlook-2003, voip

Below is the help page from Outlook 2003.
It specifies that to use outlook to connect and record the item, one must ne connected to a POTS.

I have recently switched to a voip solution for my phone needs and I would like to be able to continue to use outlook as my base of operations.
Does anyone know how I might be able to do that?

*About dialing from Outlook

If you have a modem connected to a voice telephone line, you can use Microsoft Outlook to dial any phone number you specify.
Before Outlook can make phone calls for you, you must set up your computer and a modem for automatic phone dialing. Then Outlook can dial phone numbers you specify, including phone numbers for contacts in the Outlook contacts list.*

EDIT: I have found out that Outlook will dial out using a SIP modem.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out exactly what you use this for. Are you simply using Outlook to dial numbers in your contacts so you don't have to manually dial them on your phone?
What VOIP are you using?

Comment: What I would like to do is use Outlook to track my calls. I use an internet phone (Vbuzzer). I uses to use a POTS, and I could track everything in Outlook. I miss this feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no VoIP modem available at this time (to my knowledge). We were looking into one for our phone system to support some legacy systems and fax machines but there is just nothing out there. Instead, we had to keep a few POTS lines and modems.

Comment: Thanks for this. If I can't find another way I'll give you the acceptance. I'll notate here if I can find a solution, but I believe you.

Comment: It's unfortunate since it (sounds like it) should work. ANd some have tried it (or are working on it): <http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Modem+over+VOIP> and <http://www.velocityreviews.com/FORUMS/t233766-virtual-modem-for-voip.html>

Comment: Oops. Delete the final '&gt;' in the links....

Comment: @Michael Todd - Thanks - still looking.

Comment: I followed the links and learned a lot. Thanks.

Apparently there is such a thing as a virtual modem - I think if so, there is a way to configure it to select how the number "dialed" is routed. If not, this would be a great app for Outlook. (Wish I had a clue how to design and code).

Comment: @Michael Todd.

Check this out. A dialler out of outlook.

Comment: I'll be darned. So, it'll work. It's odd that more solutions don't exist for something like this.